# Linq to SQL with Stored Procedures

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I want to add custom (compound and read-only) attributes to my stored procedure results class. When I did that, I got the error

```
LINQ - Cannot assign value to member XXX. It does not define a setter.
```

I then found this [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025144547/http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/04/20/121437.aspx) - the author suggests that decorating the partial class with the [Table] attribute will resolve the problem.

```
 1:  [Table]   
 2:  partial class GetContactsResult   
 3:  {   
 4:      public string FullName
 5:      {
 6:          get
 7:          {
 8:              return FirstName + " " + LastName;
 9:          }
10:      }
11:  }
```

But then I got this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Table' could not be found (are you missing 
a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you added the appropriate using directive?

```
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
```

Answer (score 3):

Be sure that you're `using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;` with the appropriate assembly referenced: `System.Data.Linq.dll`.

Answer (score 0):

I use read-only custom attributes in my stored procedure result classes all the time, without trouble.

However, I don't rely on auto-generated / drag-and-drop mechanisms.  Just code it yourself, and you may find the problem goes away.

(oh, and as the error message says, you're `missing a using directive`...)